# Tweeting images programmatically

Tags: image, twitter, client-side

I have a business requirement for the project that I'm working on to allow users to print, email and share an image on Facebook and Twitter. The first three are simple whereas I'm finding it impossible to find a succinct example of how to post a tweet with an image using only client side scripting. I've seen various solutions using the Twitter API and almost all of them are PHP based. Surely this can't be that difficult.

Answer (score 1):

This example uses the [TwitterAPI](https://github.com/geduldig/TwitterAPI) python library.

```
from TwitterAPI import TwitterAPI

TWEET_TEXT = 'some tweet text'
IMAGE_PATH = './some_image.png'

CONSUMER_KEY = ''
CONSUMER_SECRET = ''
ACCESS_TOKEN_KEY = ''
ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET = ''

api = TwitterAPI(CONSUMER_KEY,CONSUMER_SECRET,ACCESS_TOKEN_KEY,ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET)

# STEP 1 - upload image
file = open(IMAGE_PATH, 'rb')
data = file.read()
r = api.request('media/upload', None, {'media': data})
print('UPLOAD MEDIA SUCCESS' if r.status_code == 200 else 'UPLOAD MEDIA FAILURE')

# STEP 2 - post tweet with a reference to uploaded image
if r.status_code == 200:
    media_id = r.json()['media_id']
    r = api.request('statuses/update', {'status': TWEET_TEXT, 'media_ids': media_id})
    print('UPDATE STATUS SUCCESS' if r.status_code == 200 else 'UPDATE STATUS FAILURE')
```